# Automation test problem using Selenium and IE and IEdriverServer

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, testing, driver

I am Using Selenium 3.14.0 And IE11,IEDriverServer_Win32_3.14.0

```
      /**
 * try for 5 attemps to find element
 * 
 * @param element
 */
public void Attempt_Find_Element(WebElement element) {
    int numAttemps = 0;
    int specifiedAttempts = 30;
    boolean success = false;

    do {
        numAttemps++;
        try {
            // access the element
            success = element.isDisplayed();
            // success = true; //<--If it reaches here 
     means success
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | 
   StaleElementReferenceException  nse) {
            // one attempt failed
        }
    } while (!success || numAttemps < specifiedAttempts);

    if (!success) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't load after " + numAttemps 
   + " attempts");
    }
}
```

And I am Getting The Following Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be 
converted to Boolean: Error executing JavaScript
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08- 
02T20:19:58.91Z'System info: host: 'MAROC89', ip: '192.168.220.71', 
os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: 
'1.8.0_161'Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Any Idea Please, And if u can suggest to me annother versions to work with IE

Comment: Looks like you are getting an error in this line. success = element.isDisplayed(); As per the error message whatever value get return by element.isDisplayed is not Boolean or driver not able to convert it to boolean. Try to debug the code and check which value got return may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, because you need return something:

```java
 public boolean Attempt_Find_Element(WebElement element) {
  int numAttemps = 0;
  int specifiedAttempts = 30;
  boolean success = false;

  do {
   numAttemps++;
   try {
    success = element.isDisplayed();
   } catch (NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException nse) {

   }
  } while (!success || numAttemps < specifiedAttempts);
  if (!success) {
   System.out.println("Couldn't load after " + numAttemps + " attempts");
  }
  return success;
 }
```